# React - on click div text, change text from another div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React JS, so I'm sorry in advance for the question.

I am developing a component here (**https://codesandbox.io/s/8pkl8w6xy0**) where I have a `<div>` with text inside. Outside of this `<div>` there is **another text**.

I'm looking to find a way to **substitute** "Replace me!" with "I wanna replace that guy!", **when I click** on "I wanna replace that guy!".

So far, so good but when I click on "I wanna replace that guy!", the text inside the `<div>` doesn't change.

The component with **"Replace me!"**:

```
class TextBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    content: 'Replace me!'
  };
  this.changeContent = this.changeContent.bind(this);
}

changeContent (newContent) {
  //code to change 'Replace me!' with 'I wanna replace that guy!'
  //when I click 'I wanna replace that guy!'
  this.setState({
    content: newContent
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="content_box">{this.state.content}</div>
      <Content onClick={this.changeContent}></Content>
    </div>
  );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TextBox />, 
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The component with **"I wanna replace that guy!"**:

```
export class Content extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(e) {
  const content = e.target.value;
  this.props.onClick(content);
}

render() {
  return (
    <div onClick={this.handleClick} value="heeey" className="text_color">
      I wanna replace that guy!
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default Content;
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `e.target.value` is used for getting values from inputs, not the text content of a div (see answers below). Also, it's better not to use 'onClick' as a property name for a child component, since it has a specific meaning. Pass it with its name: `<Content changeContent={this.changeContent}/>`, then in the child's `handleClick(e)` function : `this.props.changeContent(content)`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Different solutions that work perfectly!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
handleClick(e) {
  const content = e.target.value;
  this.props.onClick(content);
}

render() {
  return (
    <div onClick={this.handleClick} value="heeey" className="text_color">
      I wanna replace that guy!
    </div>
  );
}
```

You're not actually passing any value to the `handleClick`.

You basically want to keep the content of your div in state, and then modify that.

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j1800mzrv).

Comment: Nice solution! But i have a question for you, if thats okay: Imagine I have an array and I want to pass bits of the same array through the click event. Would it be something like: `this.state = { content: this.props.content }`? Does it make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by bits of the same array. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: Imagine I have an array like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/zklkrmk8l 
The array is like a file tree and want I want to know is how should I pass the object. For example, I want to show in the box I just developed, only this: `{"type":"directory",
     "name":"./bin",
     "contents": [
      {"type":"file","name":"./bin/greet"}
     ]
    }`

Comment: Well then you'd just pass `data.whatever.whateverelse` and it works the same way.

Comment: something like `this.props.data`?

Comment: yep, I think so.

Comment: This the kind of example I was telling you earlier: https://codesandbox.io/s/509j5npkwx
@Colin

Comment: You need to pass `structure` to your `<File>`, and you shouldn't have your `renderTree` outside of a component, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: `renderTree` should be inside `class FileTree` then?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. https://codesandbox.io/s/kok29jp04o

```
  handleClick(e) {
    const content = e.target.innerHTML;  //Since it is an element it should be `.innerHTML`
    this.props.onClick(content);
  }
```

Pass the e.target.innerHTML to the content. e.target.value would've worked if the 'I wanna replace that guy!' is placed inside a text box.

Comment: You mean an `<input />`?

Comment: Yes. e.target.value would consider the element as <input /> or an form element. But in this case the element is a 'div'. So getting the innerHTML should be an appropriate one.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `e.target.value`, you should use `e.target.textContent`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19559393)

Comment: @Vinay Prajapati It does, I tried, it works and is actually faster than innerHTML.

Comment: An answer on SO should be elaborative enough. What is textContext and why it should be used in place of value should be explained here

Comment: To access the inner text of a HTML element, you can use .textContent, for more reference check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent. Is that enough @VinayPrajapati or you want me to explain the whole web API from scratch.